# batch: second for loop with spaces in dir name are not working

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, spaces

I try to use two for loops to get a simple job done:
The first for-loop brings me a list of files,
the second for-loop then should joind me the content of all files together in a tempfile (and later ftp it somewhere but thats not the problem).
So this is my code so far:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

REM FILE-MERGER
if exist "%temp%\ZS_aus_Files.csv" del /f /q "%temp%\ZS_aus_Files.csv"
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /s /b /a-d C:\Documents\accounting\') do (
        echo %%x
        for /f tokens^=*^ delims^=^ eol^= %%f IN (%%x) DO echo %%f >> %temp%\ZS_aus_Files.csv
)
```

%%x so far has the complete path in it with spaces as well.
In the second for-loop (%%x) throws an error because of the space.

Output of my code is something like:

```
C:\Documents\accounting\file with spaces.csv
The file "C:\Documents\accounting\file" cannot be found.
```

Putting (%%x) in qoutes ("%%x") makes the output a filelist instead a merged content file.

I realy stuck here, hope someone can help me with that.

Comment: I am not understanding why you are escaping all the `FOR /F` options?

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
if exist "%temp%\ZS_aus_Files.csv" del /f /q "%temp%\ZS_aus_Files.csv"
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /s /b /a-d C:\Documents\accounting\') do (
        echo %%x
        for /f usebackq^ tokens^=*^ delims^=^ eol^= %%f IN ("%%x") DO echo %%f >> %temp%\ZS_aus_Files.csv
)
```

This is not documented by MS at all in for help but when `usebackq` is used with double quotes it can be used for file names and processes file names with spaces.

Comment: It is documented in the help text of `for /?` -- see the section below the first `for /F` example...

Comment: @aschipfl - aah right.There's no example but is mentioned in the text.

Comment: I'd suggest that the `echo` should become a `type` in both the original and the response given the problem description.